# Trying to remember an ancient Greek fantasy movie, possibly video game

Tags: story-identification, movie

The only things I can remember is it was probably an ancient Greek fantasy film and has that dust/dirt/rock aesthetic of films like Clash of the Titans, it was probably of the same era as the 2010 remake, and it involved a woman hiding from villains or being trapped by them in a large metal oven like a pig on a spit, risking being cooked alive, and needing to be rescued.

Comment: Probably Hercules 2014? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules_(2014_film) The woman is Ergenia, but I am not sure about that specific scene (Ergenia is ordered to be executed and cooking alive in a similar device was especially cruel way to be executed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could this be Tarsem Singh's 2011 movie [*"Immortals"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immortals_(2011_film))?

It has a distinctive and peculiar visual style, the story has Greek gods and titans, and the other details seems to match too.

> a woman hiding from villains

She could be Phaedra, a oracle kept prisoner by the villain Hyperion to keep advantage of her visions. Later on she escapes together with Theseus.

> being trapped by them in a large metal oven like a pig on a spit

Other women are imprisoned and tortured in a brazen statue representing a bull, placed upon a fire.

Comment: That would be the legendary bronze bull of Phalaris, tyrant of Syracuse.

Comment: That's it! Thank you! Too bad you can't see anything.